# When using Autosizing in iOS storyboard how to guarantee a UITableView's cells won't be partial

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6.0

I have a table view with row height 33 and height 363. When displaying on iPhone 5 none of the table cells I add are cut off, it ends nicely and id good. The autosizing looks like:

[image: Autosizing on iPhone 5 screensize]

Now the issue is when I try this on a 3.5inch iPhone 4 screen, the last table cell is half cut off because the height is now 275. I do want the tableview to shrink but I want the height to stay a multiple of 33.

I can think of two possible ways:
1) In storyboard set the small tableview to a correct height (say 297), then is there a way to set a max size on the autosizing via storyboard?

2)Programmatically detect iPhone type and adjust in code. What is the safest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do it in code by detecting the iPhone type like #2, or if you use layout constraints, you can add a single constraint in code that relates the height of the table view to the height of the screen. The table view height can be expressed as the screen height times a multiplier plus a constant, so if you solve for these two equations, you'll get values for the multiplier and constant that will work:

568 * multiplier + constant = 363  and 480 * multiplier + constant = 297

If you work this out, it gives you multiplier = .75 and constant = -63.0115

So the code I use looks like this. I add a fudge factor of 10 to the constant I calculated to take care of padding in the table view (I determined this empirically). I created a height constraint in IB, and made an IBOutlet to it -- it doesn't matter what its value is, since I immediately remove it in viewDidLoad (it's needed in IB so the constraints will be sufficient).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten",@"Eleven",@"Twelve"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView removeConstraint:self.tableHeight];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.75 constant:-63.0115 + 10]];
}
```

Comment: He is using springs, and you are suggesting AutoLayout

Comment: @DuricanRadu, yes, either that or in code like his number 2 suggestion. There's no way to do what he wants with springs.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar, I've turned on autolayout and it hasnt busted my app so I'll go with that - in the above code though self.tableheight in the penultimate line is causing a build fail of property not found?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it works if I remove the penultimate line - but would still love to know why it didnt compile and what that line was meant to do

Comment: @Knightsy, I had a height constraint that I set in IB that was just a fixed number and belonged to the table view itself (rather than its superview). I had that in there just so the constraints I setup in IB would be non-ambiguous. That line removes that constraint, which I then replace with the one relative to the superview in the last line.